# What order Names and changes sets listed in annotate window in annotate feature in visual studio TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

What order Names and changes sets listed in annotate window in annotate feature in visual studio  TFS

[image]

Comment: Unsure what you're asking for... It shows for every line who last changed that line and when. So there isn't really an order of changeset or an order of users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no order for the Names and changessets listed, the Annotated window displays the annotated file for the code line.

Each annotation appears to the left of the text that was changed and displays:

- Changeset number, or Local if you have pending changes in your local
  workspace.
- The name of the person who made the change.
- Date.